# Define a custom map using smart pointers or reference wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, reference, smart-pointers

I've a struct as follows:

```
struct T_MY_TOY {
   uint32_t id;
   float data;
};
```

I would like to define a custom map.
My first implementation was:

```
typedef std::map<uint32_t, T_MY_TOY*> T_MY_TOY_MAP;
```

Is it correct to use, instead of `T_MY_TOY*`, a **smart pointer** or a **reference wrapper**?

```
typedef std::map<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<T_MY_TOY> > T_MY_TOY_MAP;
```

or:

```
typedef std::map<uint32_t, std::reference_wrapper<T_MY_TOY> > T_MY_TOY_MAP;
```

Which is the best solution?

Comment: What are the reasons not to store values in the map? These reasons, if any, could shed some light on which alternative is best.

Comment: Just to use less memory.

Comment: Storing pointers doesn't mean you will use less memory. They have to point to something. So I would say you have no reason not to store values. Also, compare the size of your struct to the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nearly always, the best option is to store objects.

Only store pointers or references if there's a good reason to: either because the objects aren't owned by the container, or because they are of multiple polymorphic types.

In the first case, the container doesn't own the objects. If you can guarantee that the objects won't be destroyed while still in the container, then it could store raw pointers.  Otherwise, you will need safe shared-ownership semantics by storing `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr`.

In the second case, the container does own the objects. Single ownership semantics are best managed by `unique_ptr`; although `shared_ptr` might be necessary if you need to share ownership.

Reference wrappers are used when you need a type that acts like an object rather than a pointer (i.e. that doesn't need explicit dereferencing); they're typically used with templates that expect object types. There's no need for that when you're controlling how you interact with the elements; using them rather than raw pointers would just potential cause mild confusion by hiding the indirection. Since they don't manage the objects' lifetimes, they could only be used in situations where you could use raw pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of your solutions are the best, the best solution is store by value:

```
 typedef std::map<uint32_t, T_MY_TOY> T_MY_TOY_MAP;
```